# Google Cloud CyberDuck

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a private cloud for my business. I would like to use cyberduck for each computer to connect to google cloud and synchronize. I am having trouble connecting each machine separately to the project I created. Do I need separate gmail addresses for each machine so they can simultaneously connect to the cloud? Or will this cause a conflict because they are using the same router IP address?

I am now getting a bad request error for all machines but one.